# Unable to connect Instagram account to Instagram Creator Studio

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, instagram

I have been trying to connect to Instagram Creator Studio using my Instagram creator account, unfortunately without success.

In this regard, I have been trough the steps listed in the [Official Meta Documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/428687951269163?id=203539221057259) (section: Connect your Instagram account to Creator Studio without a Facebook Page) to make sure I am taking the correct steps.

However, I consistently get the following error message:

> This Instagram account has already been connected to an existing Page.
>
> Please request access to this Page to see your Instagram account in Creator Studio.

Now, my Instagram account is not linked to my Facebook account, yet I do not want to connect the two of them but just wish to access Instagram Creator Studio using my Instagram account.

Also, I find the error message confusing when it refers to "Page": which page exactly?

What I have tried, without success:

- Sign out of your Facebook user profile, and then log in to Creator Studio using your Instagram username and password: when doing that, I am always prompted to first login by using my Facebook account (which I don't understand the reason for).
- Go to Creator Studio from a private or Incognito browser, and then log in to Creator Studio using your Instagram username and password: as for the above point, when doing that, I am always prompted to first login by using my Facebook account (which I don't understand the reason for).

Does anybody know how I can fix this or at least explain exactly what this error means?
Does this issue require support from Meta as it is something I simply cannot fix myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

go to the instagram app on your phone - sign in with the connected IG account - go to edit profile - in profile info there's a section called page - disconnect